# A Sobolev or Lebesgue space over an unbounded domain will not be separable

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Somehow it seems like it should be obvious that

> a Sobolev or Lebesgue space over an unbounded domain will not be separable

since many people state it without explanation. Could someone please tell me why?

Comment: It is so "obvious" (for $p < \infty$) that it is **false**.

Comment: @PhoemueX So a Galerkin method for weak solution for PDE will work?

Comment: I'm not sure yet about sobolev spaces, it might also depend on the regularity of the boundary, but it's not hard to see that the claim is false e.g. for $L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$ with $ 1 \leq p < \infty$: The functions of the class $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ are dense in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$. Now you can approximate any $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$-function with polynomials in the supremum norm, and because the compactness of the support this implies $L^{p}$-convergence.